# Create attribute programmatically in magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I need to create brand attribute in fabric attribute set.

```
<?php

namespace XXX\YYY\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use XXX\YYY\Model\Config\Source\Options;

class AddCustomManufacturerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    const ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'brand';

    protected $eavSetupFactory;
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    public function __construct(ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup, EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);       
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, self::ATTRIBUTE_NAME, [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'attribute' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Brand',
                'input' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => Options::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => NULL,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'used_for_sort_by' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,virtual,downloadable,bundle,configurable',
                'group' => 'Fabric Attributes',
                'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            ]
        );
        $eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'Fabric', 'Fabric Attributes', self::ATTRIBUTE_NAME, 1
        );
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

But the brand created in fabric attribute set and also default attribute set.

But,I need to create brand attribute only in fabric attribute set  .

If anything i want to change it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line ..

```
 'group' => 'Fabric Attributes',
```

Comment: how can we create multiple attributes at a time?